# A little bit of Geo-logic using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I'm going through the documentation on MongoDB and I'm still having a bit of trouble getting a few things done. However this issue is currently my largest.

I need to return from a collection all documents where the distance is under 20 miles from a set latitude and longitude position, luckily on [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) I found this gem.

```
db.places.find( {
  loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 62, 62 ], 100/3963.2 ] } }
} )
```

Which returns all documents within 100 miles of `62,62`
 obviously all I have to do is change that 100 to a 20 and I'm golden, right? Well, almost. I also need to know how many miles each document is away from the original point. For example:

```
var user {
    name: 'Thomas',
    latitude: 61,
    longitude: 62
}
```

It's common knowledge that 1 degree in latitude is `69` miles, so these documents should be 69 miles apart. Executing the original query is all well, as the document will be returned, but now I'm stuck wondering..

> Okay, so this document (user) is within 100 miles, but how far away is he?

So how would I go about adding the value into the document (only for return purposes). Coming from SQL it was quite simple (Well, kinda) and looked like this:

```
SELECT  *,
(3963.2 * acos(cos(radians(62))
        * cos(radians(latitude)) 
        * cos(radians(longitude) 
        - radians(62)) 
        + sin(radians(62)))) AS distance
FROM users;
```

Which would return the entire row (document) with the additional field of `distance` showing the mileage from 62,62.

---

EDIT: it's good to note that I'm using .aggregate() and not .find() due to the sheer amount of filtering being done on this `query(?)`.

Comment: I think, you just need to use command `geoNear` for this task, which not only gets the objects within some radius, but counts the distance at the same moment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/

Comment: It was in my understanding that `geoNear` could not be used in `.aggregate()` where I have already filtered out a lot of documents by going through about 10 different queries. (Thus reducing the amount of geographical calculations required on the server). `geoNear` definitely does what I would like, perhaps there's a way to run it `only` on the documents returned by my `.aggregate()` call? That would be the most beneficial, considering the amount of filtering that needs to be done for my application.

Comment: For example I'm filtering out users that are "already friends, blocked, already pending, already declined, not within rating standards, not x, not y, not z, not male/female, not over x age, not under x age, and then within x miles and then ordering them.  The distance calculation is the only part throwing me for a loop.

Comment: `geoNear` can be just a part of your aggregation pipeline. Here is the documentation, which explains it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: @Rodion - Is there a way I'm missing to find the special functionality inside of aggregation pipelines in the documentation? I'm only lucky to run into them when googling 1200 different combinations of words it seems.

Comment: Also, `You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.` and the default `$limit` is 100. I'm sure this is to reduce the amount of calculation (as stated in my previous post). So, my next question is, is it possible to pass a `result set/group of documents returned from a previous query` into another aggregation function, for example: `db.collections('users").find({...}).toArray(function(error, projection) { projection.aggregate()...` I would just use `{$project}` but `$geoNear` says it must be the first stage.

Comment: Unfortunately `$geoNear` can't work on results of other queries, since it needs access to original documents and their indexes. But since it returns all of the fields of the document, you can run `$geoNear` first and then apply all the rest of your filters to the result. I don't know if it helps, but you can use a `query` parameter in `$geoNear` to filter your results by `"blocked, male/female"` and other criteria you have. Or try something like that: `db.collections('users").aggregate([{'$geoNear': {}, '$match': {}, '$sort': {}])`

Comment: @Radion - I think what I've decided to do is to go ahead and stick with the use of `$geoWithin` and then have the client (mobile application) detect the difference in mileage between two points. Simply because after doing some benchmarks it's more efficient to reduce the server's load then poll by using `$geoWithin` after reducing the documents, then it is to cycle the entire collection through a `$geoNear`. The math may be the same, but the amount of times it has to do it is extremely different. (Talking around 1/30th of the results in a multi-thousand document collection)